# Getting Time Zone Name(IST,PST,DST) of system's date in java-script in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, date

I am trying to fetch the time zone name of my system's date in java-script.

In Chrome and firefox i am able to do that but in case of IE it gives me the following output

var date = new date()

my date comes out to be ("Wed Nov 27 17:46:24 UTC+0530 2013").

Clearly it does not give me any information about the time zone name.

One way is to use "UTC+0530" and then fetch the name, but two Time Zones exist 
corresponding to this value. So not be possible.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There is this javascript library which you might want to give a try:

jsTimezoneDetect : http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/

Example:

```
 var timezone = jstz.determine();
 timezone.name(); 
 --> "Asia/Kolkata"
```

Comment: This approach will not work because , even setting my system's timezone to srilanka, i am getting same "Asia/Kolkata" in my result.